# Determining TTF Font File Name

Tags: .net, fonts

If I have a .NET Font object, is there a way to programmatically determine which ttf file in the C:\Windows\Fonts directory it was created with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This helpful article](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/font-registry-t59349.html) suggests that by looking at registry key

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

You'll get a list of fontname, filename pairs. Open said registry key, iterate through the names until you find a match, then the value contains the filename (without a path).

Comment: Thanks! Actually, a couple of them in my Hive do have full path.  So it looks like its assumed to be in the system fonts folder, unless it has a full path, in which case its that path. Either way, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Nick: One thing to note is that those in the registry hive don't actually match the Font.Name - they are usually appended with something in the Registry key like "(TrueType)" as in `Arial (TrueType)". This works, most of the time, to just use a RegEx to normalize a font name by removing the appending descriptor, but not always. My need was similar to yours, but I needed exactness, including potentially foreign language names for fonts. So what I did was grabbed all font file names from the hive and read each ttf or ttc's header file to extract the name to match it to an installed font name.